# Using docker/docker-machine in multiple Terminal tabs on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, docker-machine

I had docker wokring in one tab but started using it for something else. I opened a new tab and tried to run `docker build` but got this error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Running `docker-machine env default` gave this error:

```
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
```

I then ran `docker-machine start default` got this (it hung forever):

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
```

When I closed the original tab I had used docker in, I then ran `docker-machine start default` again and got:

```
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.
```

And everything works fine in that tab now.

How do I get docker commands to work in more than one Terminal tab?

Comment: This is still an issue for me, everytime I get these errors I have to reboot my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

Execute this command in each terminal you want to use Docker.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: I did, that command gave me: "Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running"

Comment: This error message means your docker is not running. Start with `docker-machine start default`. To make sure your docker is not running when you execute this command, restart your Mac.

Comment: I did. You are trying to start docker-macine when it is running. That's why I said to restart your Mac. If you had read the document/ did a Google search you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: techtabu's original post is the correct approach (which of course is what you already tried).
It seems like the tab you were using encountered some problem, whereby the docker machine was running but it could neither connect to it nor start it. You understandably assumed you were doing something wrong, but you weren't.
I would expect this to be an isolated occurrence, but it could be a sign of an ongoing problem or a bad install or something...

If it persists I'd recommend removing the machine and starting with a fresh one.

Answer (score 4):

On OS X (with Core2Duo) you should normally use the **Docker QuickStart Terminal.app**. It does for you the command

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

More exactly it does

```
bash -c "clear && DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 \
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/metzger9/.docker/machine/machines/de‌​fault \
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 /bin/bash"
```

You can see it with a CTRL-D, which logout the session, and then find the last command with the upper arrow.

The best solution is to record the result of

```
docker-machine env default
```

in your **.bash_profile**. The next time you open a OS X Terminal you will have the

```
env
```

variables needed to make docker run (nearly as natively)